# How to join two strings in a SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, string-concatenation

I got the following query:

```
SELECT
  IF(e.business_id IS NOT NULL, b.name, SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.names, ' ', 1)) as name,
  f.code,
  f.total,
  f.date
FROM business AS b INNER JOIN entity AS e ON b.id = e.business_id
  INNER JOIN persons AS p ON e.person_id = p.id
  INNER JOIN transactions AS t ON e.id = t.entity_id
  INNER JOIN bills AS bi ON t.id = bi.transaction_id
  WHERE e.type = 2 AND t.type_id = 1;
```

If `business_id` at `entity` table is null, I need join one name and  one surname from the person. I store in a field called `names` the persons name — e.g. Steven Paul - and the in a field called `surnames` the persons surname — e.g. Jobs Jobs.

So far I got the name with `SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.names, ' ', 1)` but how do I join that string to `SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.surnames, ' ', 1)` separated by a space?

Comment: Have you tried reading about the [String Functions in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html)?

Comment: to join two strings you should use  CONCAT  or CONTACT_WS, like  select CONCAT(tbl.firstname, " " ,tbl.lastname) as full_name from table;

Comment: hi there, going through some of my old answers. Did you manage to sort this one out?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you are really looking for is [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

> Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no
>   non-NULL values.

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(e.business_id, CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.names, ' ', 1),' ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.surnames, ' ', 1)) ...
```